# Visual Studio Code: How do I prevent it from inserting */ when I type /*?

Tags: autocomplete, visual-studio-code

When editing C# code (and possibly other languages as well), when I type `/*` VS Code will automatically insert `*/`. This is quite annoying to me.

How can I disable this behavior? I haven't been able to find a setting for it, and doing web searches for `/*` or `*/` is pretty much impossible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems that there's a way to do this in Visual Studio Code, though there's an issue tracking it: [Microsoft/vscode#1966.](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1966)

Comment: I assume you mean "there's not a way to do this" or something to that effect.